# How to generate sonar report with sonarqube version 9.2.1.49989. Which plugin i need to install for that?

Tags: sonarqube

How to generate sonar report with sonarqube version 9.2.1.49989. Which plugin i need to install for that?

I installed CNES Report .jar plugin to generate sonar report but this plugin(CNES) not supporting could you please help  how to generate sonarqube report in latest sonarqube version 9.2.1.49989.

Answer (score 0):

Sonar CNES plugin works on LTS versions of Sonarqube. Please check the support matrix here https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/.

However you can try as described in this ticket https://community.sonarsource.com/t/unable-to-generate-sonar-cnes-report/58039.